# how to attach a class to a view in the main story board

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, storyboard

I am new to XCode 4.2 , and I am trying to find a way to attach a class (.h and .m files) to a view in my main storyBoard ... how can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it's a subclass of UIViewController, you can assign in interface builder in xcode. 
Open the .xib, select your view, open the properties and assign a custom class 
Here is a screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/fl4up.jpg