# How to attach a class to a storyboard in XCode 5

Tags: storyboard, xcode5

I've tried googling for a solution for how to attach a class to a storyboard in XCode 5.  I found [how to attach a class to a view in the main story board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8855526/how-to-attach-a-class-to-a-view-in-the-main-story-board), however, I cannot recreate this drop-down menu.  Is anyone able to offer me guidance as to how to do this in XCode 5?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a class to a ViewController, or a TableViewController for example. The storyboard is no more than an editor to set up these objects.

You can have a storyboard for iPad, one for 3.5 inch iPhones, and one for 4 inch iPhones.

Comment: Ok, I'm still not sure how to check I am doing this right.  If when I run it on the emulator a table view comes up as expected, does this mean my project is ok?

Comment: Yeah that should be mean have set your ViewControllers class properly. What you want to do is open your storyboard, zoom all the way out, click once on your ViewController, then under the "identity inspector", (third item on the right panel), set custom class